# Не могу установить psycopg2 на линуксе

Tags: python, django, psycopg2

Пытаюсь подключить postgresql к своему проекту на Django. И когда пытаюсь установить psycopg2 то выходит следующая ошибка

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement psycopg2-binary (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for psycopg2-binary
```

Пытался установить как и binary так и обычную. Как я понял из документации библиотека не поддерживает некоторые версии пайтон, поэтому в виртуальном окружении я поменял ее на 3.11(версия psycopg2.9.9 поддерживается до версии пайтон 3.12), но это не помогло. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Библиотека называется psycopg2, у вас ошибка в написании названия

Comment: Капец, все спасибо

Comment: Целый день мучался не мог понять что не так